# The use of What as a relative pronoun

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, which-what, adjectival-phrases

I was doing a TOEFL exercise and I stumbled on this particular error-analysis question:

> In the Indus Valley, what is now Pakistan and western India, most dwellings had drains for waste disposal.

The use of "what" in that sentence is markedly correct, while "which" incorrect. Why is "what" correct in that use? Why not "which" that serves better as a relative pronoun?

Comment: That sentence is awful. However, "in what is now x" is a journalistic or historical expression. Most dwellings in the Indus Valley, in what is now part of Pakistan and Western India, had disposal drains. "what is now x" is correct, but not in the way it is found in that sentence which is agrammatical for English grammar. The structure is appositional.

Comment: I don't think "what" is a relative pronoun there: What was once true is now false. What was once [some place] is now [some other place]. But it gets complicated when you add the preposition *in,* and I'll leave defining the grammar to someone else.

Comment: When you say "markedly" (meaning that the phrasing stands out or is unusual), did you mean "marked" (assessed by someone)?

Comment: I found this sentence — _In the Indus Valley **in** what is now Pakistan and western India, most dwellings had drains for waste disposal by about 2500 B.C._ — [here](https://patents.justia.com/patent/6237164). So my question is: Are you sure you copied the test question correctly? If so, I would say the test is incorrect. The sentence here is correct. (And *what* means *that which*.)

Comment: The correctness or otherwise of the sentence depends, for me, on whether the whole of Pakistan and Western India are in the Indus valley. If they are then the sentence is correct, if there are other regions of Pakistan and Western India (which I believe to be the case) the statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

The use of *what* as a normal relative pronoun is common in some varieties of English, but non-standard:

> ? The man what I saw was wearing a hat

But *what* is normal as a [fused relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun#Antecedents), meaning "the one which", or "the thing which", or (more literary) "that which", eg.

> I gave him *what he wanted*.

The example you give is tricky, because it is possible to read it as a normal relative clause qualifying "the Indus valley", and in that construction, *what* would be non-standard, and *which* would be normal.

But it is more natural to read it as a free relative clause, paraphrasable as "In the Indus valley, *the region which* is now Pakistan and Western India".  That seems the more natural reading to me, and I'm sure it's what the writers of the test intended.

But I can't work out why I think it is a more natural reading. I *think* this construction is quite common when talking about historical places, but I haven't found way to verify this.

Comment: "What is now" is idiomatic when we refer to historical boundaries.  A Google search provides several examples: [**1**](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/The_Cyclopedia_of_Tasmania/jsNBAQAAMAAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=1&bsq=%22what+is+now+part+of%22&dq=%22what+is+now+part+of%22&printsec=frontcover),[**2**](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Miscellaneous_National_Park_and_National/_ngtaGlvgn0C?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=1&dq=%22what+is+now+part+of%22&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover), etc.

Comment: Yes, what is now is used to describe a name change. Generally: in what is now x.

Comment: Upon my initial reading of the sentence, I mentally paraphrased it as including the word "in"... i.e. "In the Indus valley, *which is in* what is now Pakistan and Western India..."  I'm not sure the author of the source material necessarily meant to equate the region of the Indus valley with the entirety of Pakistan and Western India, which (to me) would be more strongly implied by using the word "which."

Comment: The sentence as posted is not grammatical in English and it's not  accurate geographically either.

Comment: 'In what is now Pakistan and western India, most dwellings had drains for waste disposal.' simplifies the sentence and is indisputably correct from an EL perspective. Formal, but not unnatural sounding (the use of the fused relative [here = 'the land which'] after the preposition). Adding an appositive (some would say inserting a NP making this an appositive) does not affect grammaticality. // ELU is not here to comment on factual accuracy; fictional regions could be substituted.

Comment: No reading is natural. The two "readings" are simply two different pronunciations of the sentence, with two different structures and meanings. The fact that it has to be written in English orthography causes the apparent ambiguity, in writing only. Real language has different problems from written language.